# How can fix java script code to import cvs file

Tags: php, csv

This code import data from csv file 
but the problem is when insert any data 
it come like this
item1;  item2;  item3;

The problem is each item have semicolon in database 
and that is not in csv file(semicolon). 
How can fix this code?

```
 <?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    require_once 'PublicFolder/DBConnection.php';

    //Import uploaded file to Database
    $handle = fopen($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'], "r");

    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000)) !== FALSE) {
        mysql_query("INSERT into data (user_name, first_name, last_name, date_added)
    values('$data[0]', '$data[1]', '$data[2]', NOW())");

    }
}

fclose($handle);
```

Comment: What code is _this code_

Comment: If your code is literally `( )` then that might explain why it's not importing CSV files...

Comment: this is not javascript :D

Comment: Format Error on line 15: parse error, unexpected $end(), expecting '}'

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You will have to use the correct delimiter (in this case, a semicolon)

```
// -------------------------------------v------------- //
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ';')) !== FALSE) {
    mysql_query("INSERT into data (user_name, first_name, last_name, date_added)
    values('$data[0]', '$data[1]', '$data[2]', NOW())");
}
```

Comment: The `utf8_encode()` function will attempt to encode a string as `utf-8`. However, this only works for the 'ISO-8859-1' encoding so you may have to use `mb_convert_encoding()` or `iconv()` to convert your specific encoding to `utf-8`